# Where to get Tersoff and SW potentials for LAMMPS

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, surfaces, forcefields, interatomic-potentials

I want to do some molecular dynamics simulations for silicene with hydrogen and halogen atoms deposited at the surface. Where can I find Stillinger-Weber potentials to use for this? There doesn't seem to be any available in the list of potentials in the LAMMPS installation.

Comment: +1 and welcome back! Why don't you say hello at least once in our [LAMMPS chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109805/lammps)? We've added some new features to it recently :)

Answer (score 9):

Generally, if you want to perform simulations with some force field, you will have to **search the literature** for published FFs tailored for your problem. The Stillinger-Weber (SW) model is very popular to describe bulk (diamond) silicon, for which it was designed in the first place. But several reparametrizations have also been published. **If** you happen to find the publication that matches your interest, you'll have to see if the authors provide a suitable parameter file themselves, or if you can make one yourself based on the published parameters. If you closely follow the [descriptions in the LAMMPS manual](https://docs.lammps.org/pair_sw.html), this is not too hard for SW. But you will have to run some benchmark calculations before you use it for production simulations.

You may also take a look at the [NIST potentials database](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/potentials/), which collects many FFs for various systems, most of which are provided in LAMMPS-readable format. If you click on Si, you will find many FFs, some of which are in fact parametrized for silicene in particular (references are also provided for all FFs). I do not see multi-component systems, though, which are generally much harder to parametrize.

Comment: Is it possible to modify an existing potential file, say for example, SiC.sw so that it would describe interactions between Si and H atoms instead of Carbon? How would I go about doing that

Comment: @Jboy , There are certain tool which is quite handy to create your own Sw potential as well as tersoff potential. Only thing you need fitted parameter from some literatures.https://dftfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/potentials.html   and https://openkim.org/id/Three_Body_Stillinger_Weber__MD_335816936951_002

Comment: use this paper https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4863841 for parameter and https://dftfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/potentials.html to generate Si-H sw potential